# Flutter avoid overflow overall?

Tags: flutter

I'm stuck in a dilemma where i'm afraid that users will get problem with overflow, due to different screen sizes. There are some solutions to this problem such as `Expanded` but still possible to get overflow. So only way to combat this is to use for e.g `ListView` everywhere. Then screen size does not matter, you will never get any overflow issue. So my question is should i worry much? Or should i use `ListView` everywhere instead of `Column` or `Row` to avoid the problem?

```
class _MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 450,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

If i change `Column` to Listview, then no more overflow issue

Answer (score 0):

Just add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use SingleChildScrollView:

```
class _MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const _MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 450,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(child:
         Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your column with singlechild-scrollview widget.